# display list of menu auto height and width bootstrap html5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, html, css

I want to display menus in this format..It should fill the first column and then next one so that if there are less submenu then it should adjust the height accordingly.. and On mobile it should display only the headings..
Please tell me how to display using bootstrap .I iwll convert to asp.net to fetch from database.Image attached 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjEkk.jpg

Comment: Just to clarify, you need all of the lists to be the same height?

Comment: use all 3 columns height to be same...otherwise it will not look perfect

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 tried so far to solve your problem.